# webRequest listener doesn't see headers like 'cookie', 'referer', 'origin'

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-extension, http-headers

We wrote a Chrome-extension that, using the onBeforeSendHeaders event, adds a cookie to each web request:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(addCookie, {
    urls: ["<all_urls>"]
}, ["blocking", "requestHeaders"]);

function addCookie(details) {
    if (details.url.match(/ourWebsite/)) {
        details.requestHeaders.forEach(function (requestHeader) {
            if (requestHeader.name.toLowerCase() === "cookie") {
                //Code that adds a cookie with a value
            }
        });
        return {requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders};
    }
}
```

It works fine on everyone's Chrome but my own. While debugging the extension, I noticed that the `details.requestHeaders` array doesn't have the `cookie` header (this is always false: `requestHeader.name.toLowerCase() === "cookie"`).

My first thought was another extension is messing up with ours, so I tried in incognito (where no other extensions are allowed) but it didn't work.

In the extension's manifest we have both "cookies" and "webRequest" under `permissions`.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @wOxxOm isn't `Set-Cookie` a response header? We're trying to modify request headers

Answer (score 11):

According to this https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest

> - Starting from Chrome 72, the following request headers are not provided and cannot be modified or removed without specifying 'extraHeaders' in opt_extraInfoSpec:
>
>   - Accept-Language
>   - Accept-Encoding
>   - Referer
>   - Cookie
> - since Chrome 79:
>
>   - Origin
>   - CORS preflight requests

> Response headers for other listeners like onHeadersReceived:
>
> - since Chrome 72:
>
>   - Set-Cookie
>   - any header you want to modify before [CORB](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/services/network/cross_origin_read_blocking_explainer.md) is applied
> - since Chrome 79:
>
>   - CORS preflight responses

So you should add "extraHeaders" to the third parameter of the webRequest listener and it should be `["blocking", "requestHeaders", "extraHeaders"]` for your example.

Note that it won't run in old pre-72 Chrome, which doesn't know about `extraHeaders`, so you can use the following trick to have a universally compatible listener:

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
  addCookie,
  {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
  ["blocking", "requestHeaders",
   chrome.webRequest.OnBeforeSendHeadersOptions.EXTRA_HEADERS].filter(Boolean)
);
```